# How to unwrap a List<Map>, group by Map keys and reduce by Map values

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<Map<String, Double>>` representing some calculations that are stored by 'category' in the `Map` key.

```
[{a: 1, b:2}, {a:4, b:5})
```

I want to calculate the average by 'category', something like: `{a: 2.5 , b: 3.5}`.

I tried with something like

```
.collector(Collectors.groupingBy..)
```

but the first parameter requests to provide the discrimination function, which I do not know how to fish it from the `Map` item.

Any idea how to do that with Java8? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to extract all the entries of all the maps into a single `Stream`. Then you can group them by the key and calculate the average of the values.

```
Map<String,Double> average =
    list.stream()
        .flatMap(m->m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                       Collectors.averagingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collectors.averagingDouble` as downstream

```
return listOfMap.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.averagingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```